# How to make a full window page height border for divider?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm attempting to make a login page for a website, https://essaydapp.com to submit and try and get into the application. I'm trying to mimic their design (see link) but I'm having some issues:

Screenshots:

1. https://imgur.com/w2GAphF
2. https://imgur.com/rimWY0s

In the first screenshot you can see the little 1px dashed border, I would like that to be the height of the entire page rather than the form only.
In the second screenshot you can see on the edges of the page and top there is the white color, but I would like that to be blue too.
 
 Thanks for any help in advance.

```css
form {
  /*border: 10px solid #1acebc;*/
  padding: 28px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-left-style: dashed;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-right-style: dashed;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

button {
  background-color: #09c;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #1acebc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: #e7f3f6;
  /*border-left: 250px solid #007da5;
  border-right: 250px solid #007da5;*/
  border-left: 175px solid #007da5;
  border-right: 175px solid #007da5;
  padding-top: 175px;
  padding-bottom: 215px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png" alt="profilepicture">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="button" name="Login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Provide a snippet with the required code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kastel/pen/VMEayr Here's a codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code is somewhat messy. Instead, I suggest to use the following flex-box solution

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #007da5;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  width: 75%; /*Set the width required*/
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #e7f3f6;
  border-left: 1px dashed black;
  border-right: 1px dashed black;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

button {
  background-color: #09c;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 85%;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #1acebc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ihZBCxx.png" alt="profilepicture">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="button" name="Login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That did exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! Sorry for the messy code, pretty new to programming, and thanks for the improved profile picture too! :^)

Comment: There you go, perhaps you can try again ;)

Answer (score 1):

This code removes any padding from left and right.
I hope that's what you want.

```
body{
    border: 1px dashed;
    backgroud-color: #e7f3f6;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```